# MySQL のroot passwordが問われます。 --skip-grant-tablesは使えません。

Tags: mysql, amazon-linux

MySQL の root password が問われます。`--skip-grant-tables` は使えません。

```
$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

となりログインすることができません。
どうすれば良いでしょうか？

```
$ sudo systemctl stop mysqld.service
$ sudo systemctl start mysqld.service --skip-grant-tables
systemctl: unrecognized option '--skip-grant-tables'
```

```
$ sudo systemctl start mysqld.service
$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

インストールの履歴

```
 1  sudo yum localinstall https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el7-1.noarch.rpm -y
 2  sudo yum-config-manager --disable mysql80-community
 3  sudo yum-config-manager --enable mysql57-community
 4  yum info mysql-community-server
 5  sudo yum install mysql-community-server -y
 6  mysqld --version
```

Comment: それで、質問は何ですか？　状況報告だけで質問が無いように見えます。まあ普通には `systemctl` に `--skip-grant-tables` を渡してもそりゃ知らんと言われて当然だと思う。

Comment: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)となりログインできません　どのようにすればログインできるようになりますか？教えていただけると幸いです

Answer (score 1):

ログファイルに初期パスワードが記載されているようなので、そちらを確認してログインを試してみてください。

**参考:**
[AWS EC2 AmazonLinux2 MySQL rootユーザの初期パスワードの確認方法 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/miriwo/items/457d6dbf02864f3bf296)

```
$ sudo less /var/log/mysqld.log

YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.260490Z 6 [Note] [MY-010454] [Server] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

末尾の `XXXXXXXXXXXX` の部分がパスワード

```
$ mysql -u root -p
 > 先ほど確認したパスワードを入力
```

Answer (score 1):

[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) もバージョンアップによって仕様が変わっています。 MySQL8 においては MySQL5 の時代の解説ページの内容を参照すると痛い目を見ることがあります。 `mysql.com` 本家の解説を見たほうが良いでしょう。

MySQL8 をインストールした直後の状態だと `root` の初期パスワードが自動生成されてログファイルに記録される、という解説が[本家マニュアルページ](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/ja/default-privileges.html)にあります。なので、今回の場合は MySQL ログファイル自体を探して、ログファイル中のログ記載からパスワードを探す、のが正規の手段だと思われます。ログファイルが `/var/log/mysqld.log` だとわかっていればこれをエディタで開いて検索する `vim /var/log/mysqld.log` とか普通に検索する `grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log` とよさそう。初期パスワードがわかれば `mysql` コマンドにこれを与えればログインできるはず。
# `sudo` 略

初期パスワードは擬似乱数で生成されているようです。実運用環境で初期パスワードをそのまま使い続けるのが適切かどうかは管理者（あなた）の判断によります。変更するもよし、しないもよし。

質問本文にある `mysqld --skip-grant-table` で MySQL を起動しなおすという手続きは `root` パスワードを忘れた等の理由によってパスワードを強制再設定するためのものなので、新規インストールした直後にすべきではありません。忘れてください。